# Profiling injected library written in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, profiling, hook

Suppose I have a library that will be injected in some process (managed or unmanaged) to hook some WinAPI calls. And I want to profile it to see if there is much overhead in some hooks. I'm using EasyHook to hook WinAPI calls and library is written in C# for .NET 3.5. Is there a way to profile library in such situation?

Comment: what exactly do you want to profile?

Comment: Time that it takes to execute hooks. Memory, maybe, but there are no memory-intensive tasks there.

Comment: What is the point of this?  You are not going to hook if you find out it takes too long?  If that's an option then don't hook in the first place, it only ever destabilizes a program.  You'd otherwise profile exactly the same way you would with regular code.

Comment: There is no way I can remove hooks, but I want to find maybe some bottlenecks and get rid of them. Isn't that a purpose of profiling, to see where your application or library is slow and try to make the code faster, not in deciding whether to remove code or not.